# customized ABNewPersonViewController screen with image editing option for the profile picture?

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

customized  ABNewPersonViewController screen with image editing option for the profile picture? can we do customized ABNewPersonViewController? is it possible to do it?I have taken one table and creating custom contact,now i am trying for image editing?can we do customized ABNewPersonViewController? is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can not customize the ABNewPersonViewController it is predefined by apple and you don;t have access to change it.
But you can always make an editing view for the user image.

Comment: can i know whether there is any code for it to edit an image and send it another controller,so that edited image will be saved into thumbnail.

Comment: Can you try to explain better what you need?

Comment: I have one image after scaling and moving transformation how to save that image with the scaling and moving coordinates